# Airflow Ooops Page

Tags: airflow

When attempting to see the logs, Airflow throws an oops page with the following message:

```
File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 486, in _parse_localename
raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
```

ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

So I followed the recommendations to add the lines:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and verfied:

```
(airflow-local) user-mbp:Desktop user$ echo $LC_ALL
en_US.UTF-8
(airflow-local) user-mbp:Desktop user$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

But that error is still showing. What's the missing thing that needs to be done?

Comment: In my particular case it helped to export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 as well.

Comment: any update on this question? I am also stuck here

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the issue.

If you are in the virtual environment.

Type `echo $LANG` in the terminal.
It will show an empty output.

Now run this command `source ~/.bash_profile`

and again run `echo $LANG`.
the response will show like this:- `en_US.UTF-8`

Restart the server and scheduler and you can see the logs from the UI.

P.S :- do all stuff in a single terminal window.